# SQL Using CONTAINS() doesn't work for AND & OR

Tags: sql, t-sql

I use Contains for detect if in some columns contains some word,.. in case with 'And' & 'Or' result is false

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CONTAINS(Keywords, 'AND')
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CONTAINS(Keywords, 'And')
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CONTAINS(Keywords, 'and')

SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CONTAINS(Keywords, 'Or')
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CONTAINS(Keywords, 'or')
```

how detect if this words :**"AND", "And", "and", "OR", "or"** is contains in products columns?

Comment: So it's returning results, but not returning fields with `And` or `Or` in them?

Comment: @franglais returns no result

Comment: Do you really mean to use a full-text search (what `CONTAINS` does) or do you just mean `WHERE Keywords LIKE '% AND %'`?

Comment: @JeroenMostert in my case I need to use only contains

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely the stop words list.  When creating the index, the default behavior is to use the system supplied stop words list:

> STOPLIST [ = ] { OFF | SYSTEM | stoplist_name }
>
> Associates a full-text stoplist with the index. The index is not
>   populated with any tokens that are part of the specified stoplist. **If
>   STOPLIST is not specified, SQL Server associates the system full-text
>   stoplist with the index.**

The words "AND" and "OR" would typically be in such a list.

You can turn it off by using `STOPLIST = OFF` when you create the index.  Or, by creating your own stop word list (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551.aspx)).

Comment: In addition to this, since `AND` and `OR` are also keywords in the search condition, quoting them may be necessary: `CONTAINS(Keywords, '"AND"')`. Disclaimer: I don't know if it actually is necessary.